# Syntax error Begin statement HDL 9-806

Tags: vhdl, error, hdl, debounce, sequence-detector

I have an error in the form of HDL 9-806 on the begin statement.
The code below is a button based sequence detector an addition LED flash when sequence is correct with a debouncer to stop multiple distorted inputs.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Code is

port(

clk :in std_logic;

clr:in std_logic;

btnd, btnl, btnu, btnr: in std_logic;

led: out std_logic_vector(0 to 7));

end Code;





architecture Behavioral of Code is

type state_type is (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);

SIGNAL state : STATE_TYPE;

signal flash: std_Logic_vector(7 downto 0)





Begin

process(clk) 

begin

if (clr = '1') then

led<=0
state <= s0;

ELSIF(rising_edge(clk)) then

case state is



when s0=>

if btnd='1' then

state <=s1;

else

state <=s0;

end if;

endcase;

end process(clk)

end;




when s1=>

if btnr='1' then

state <=s2;

else

state<=s1;

end if;




when s2 =>

if btnl='1' then

state <= s3;

else

state <=s1;

end if;




when s3=>

if btnu='1' then

state<= s4;

else

state<=s1;

end if;



when s4=>

if btnu='1' then

state<=s5;

flash => not flash

led=> flash

else

state<=s1;

end if;

end case;

end if;

end process;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few syntax errors

semicolons afer

- signal flash: std_Logic_vector(7 downto 0)
- flash => not flash
- led => flash
- led <= 0

the signal assignment to "flash" and "led" needs to be turned around (<= instead of =>).

endcase; end process(clk) and end; in the middle of your code is misplaced. You try to open a process and a case statement once and close it twice.

led<=0; needs to become led<= (others => '0'); since it is a std_logic_vector

end architecture; is missing

The case statement only covers 5 out of the 6 possible states.

your code without syntax errors:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Code is

port(
    clk :in std_logic;
    clr:in std_logic;
    btnd, btnl, btnu, btnr: in std_logic;
    led: out std_logic_vector(0 to 7));
end Code;

architecture Behavioral of Code is

    type state_type is (s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);

    SIGNAL state : STATE_TYPE;
    signal flash: std_Logic_vector(7 downto 0);

Begin

    process(clk) 

    begin
        if (clr = '1') then
            led<= (others => '0');
            state <= s0;
        ELSIF(rising_edge(clk)) then
            case state is
                when s0=>
                    if btnd='1' then
                    state <=s1;
                    else
                    state <=s0;
                    end if;

                when s1=>
                    if btnr='1' then
                    state <=s2;
                    else
                    state<=s1;
                    end if;

                when s2 =>
                    if btnl='1' then
                    state <= s3;
                    else
                    state <=s1;
                    end if;

                when s3=>
                    if btnu='1' then
                    state<= s4;
                    else
                    state<=s1;
                    end if;

                when s4=>
                    if btnu='1' then
                    state<=s5;
                    flash <= not flash;
                    led <= flash;
                    else
                    state<=s1;
                    end if;
                when s5 =>
                    -- do something here
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Good answer. Even better than "when s5 =>" would be "when others =>", no?